# How do I get serval activities to show in a Swipe View using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, swipeview

I was trying to get serval activities into one Swipe View.

I tried this tutorial :[Implementing Horizontal View Swiping Using ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/)
_

How can I get an activity to show in a section instead of showing that textView (like in the tutorial) using Intent? (or any other way).
Thanks!

Comment: You can't get activities there, you must use fragments

Comment: How can I convert my activity to a fragment?

Comment: This is something you can google or learn by reading what fragments are and how they work

Answer (score 0):

In Step 8. and 9.
What you need to do is to return your different MyFragment 1.2.3 etc ( converted from your Activities) in the getItem() method of the MyFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    //MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    //Bundle data = new Bundle();
    //data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
    //myFragment.setArguments(data);
    //return myFragment;

//a switch returning different types Fragments
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        //Previous Activity 1, "converted to a Fragment":)
        return (mMyFragment1 = new MyFragment1());
    case 1:
        //Previous Activity 2, "converted to a Fragment":)
        return (mMyFragment2 = new MyFragment2());
    }
}
```

Note: There is a quicker way to implement the code from that tutorial:
Make sure you have the latest SDK tools and platform-tools installed from the Android SDK Manager.
In step 4. of the tutorial you tried, "Enter MainActivity details"
Select Navigation type: Swipe Views + Title Strips and your good to go.

Example Fragment with comments

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
//Empty Constructor
public MyFragment () {
}   
//Return a new instance with FragmentArguments
public static MyFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Fragments Inflate the content view here, 
//Activities use: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 //Fragments initialize views here (or you could do it in the onCreateView() method), 
 //Activities do it in the OnCreate() method
TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textview.setText(
         "Implement all your old Activity methods here, " +
         "but remember to use getActivity() instead of THIS. !!!" +
         "A Fragment is a child of the parent Activity" +
         "--One Activity to rule them all--"     
         );


////let the argument decide what you want to do. here it is the position in the FragmentPagerAdapter
//   final int position;
//   if (getArguments() != null) {
//          position = getArguments().getInt(MyConfig.ADAPTER_POSITION_KEY);
//   } 
    }//END onViewCreated()

//      //Let the Activity implement a callback interface to communicate back. 
//      public interface Callbacks {
//          public void onCallback(int adId);
//      }
//      private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
//          @Override
//          public void onCallback(int adId) {
//          }
//      };
//      private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
//      @Override
//      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
//          super.onAttach(activity);
//          if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
//              throw new ClassCastException(
//                      "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
//          }
//          mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
//      }
    //
//      @Override
//      public void onDetach() {
//          super.onDetach();
//          mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
//      }    

}
```